# Professional skills advising for math jobs

Tags: teaching

Hi,

I am a postdoc at the University of Nottingham (UK) and I am beginning to apply for Assistant Professor positions in US.
I would like to receive a feedback on the material that I am sending (mainly the teaching statement).
Does anyone know any professional skills advising website which is specific for scientific jobs?
For humanities faculty jobs I have noticed:

http://theprofessorisin.com/

Thank you for your attention,

Daniele Muraro

Comment: Not really appropriate for this site, so I am voting to close, but just as a side point, unless you are applying to, e.g., Williams College, the teaching statement is the least of your problems.

Comment: This is what mentors (eg postdoc mentors, PhD advisors, etc) are for.  Surely there is some senior person you trust who is willing to give you advice!